# display none breaks chart.js when selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show only one chart after the page load and then you can select a chart in the dropdown menu. The issues is when I add the class `display:none;` the graph won't load when selected in the dropdown.

How can I solve this?

```
<select id='chart-graph-progress'>
    <option value="revenue-opt">Revenue</option>
    <option value="rpu-opt">Revenue per user</option>
</select>

<div class="card2 full-chart-topmargin" id='revenue'>
    <div class="big-text1-blue text-center">
        Revenue
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="chart-wrapper fullsize">
            <canvas id="revenue-chart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" class="card2 full-chart-topmargin" id='rpu'>
    <div class="big-text1-blue text-center">
        Revenue per user
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="chart-wrapper fullsize">
            <canvas id="rpu-chart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my custom.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chart-graph-progress').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'revenue-opt')
          {
            $("#revenue").show();
          }
          else
          {
            $("#revenue").hide();
          }
    });
    $('#chart-graph-progress').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'rpu-opt')
          {
            $("#rpu").show();
          }
          else
          {
            $("#rpu").hide();
          }
    });
});
```

Chart.js

```
  var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
  var lineChartData = {
    labels : ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: 'Revenue',
        labelColor : '#fff',
        fontColor : '#fff' ,
        backgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        borderColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBorderColor : '#fff',
        data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
      }
    ]
  };

  var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
         display: false,
         color: '#03A5C5',
         lineWidth: 8,
         },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
         display: false,
         color: '#03A5C5',
         lineWidth: 8,
         },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById('revenue-chart');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    responsive: true,
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: options
  });

  var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
  var lineChartData = {
    labels : ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label: 'Revenue',
        labelColor : '#fff',
        fontColor : '#fff' ,
        backgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        borderColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointBorderColor : '#fff',
        data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
      }
    ]
  };

  var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
         display: false,
         color: '#03A5C5',
         lineWidth: 8,
         },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
         display: false,
         color: '#03A5C5',
         lineWidth: 8,
         },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "white",
          beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }]
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById('rpu-chart');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    responsive: true,
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: options
  });
```

Comment: May I ask what graph? From the HTML and JS code provided, everything looks fine and your code doesn't contain any graph. Are you using ChartJS or some other libraries to initialize a graph? If so, please provide those code as well.

Comment: @nelsonyeung Thanks for your answer. I have the graph in a separate chart.js. The graph is showing when I remove the display:none. Editing and adding the code now :)

Comment: @nelsonyeung Updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ChartJS 1, then look at the first possible fixes below. If you are using ChartJS 2, then apparently this bug has been fixed ([GitHub issue #762](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/762)). However, after some long debugging I found out that when `display: none;` is used with `maintainAspectRatio: false`, some times the height of the graph is squashed to none, which I think it's your problem here. I have logged an [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4659) for this.

**Possible fixes (1 is very simple, so you might want to try that):**

**1. Use jQuery to initially hide the containers**

Remove the `style="display:none;"` from the `#rpu` `div`:

```
<div class="card2 full-chart-topmargin" id='rpu'>
```

Use jQuery to hide it initially:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rpu").hide();

  // ...
});
```

**2. Use fixed size canvases**

Set both canvas to some fixed size:

```
<canvas id="revenue-chart"  width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<canvas id="rpu-chart"  width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Then use `maintainAspectRatio: true` instead:

```
var options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the html, on the element with the id='rpu' try to add "opacity: 0" instead of "display: none", and in the custom.js file instead of show and hide change to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chart-graph-progress').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'revenue-opt')
          {
            $("#revenue").css("opacity", "1");
          }
          else
          {
            $("#revenue").css("opacity", "0");
          }
    });
    $('#chart-graph-progress').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'rpu-opt')
          {
            $("#rpu").css("opacity", "1");
          }
          else
          {
            $("#rpu").css("opacity", "0");
          }
    });
});
```

I am pretty sure that the issue is that the chart is not initialized on a display: none element. So we're trying to hide the element by opacity:0.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! It works but the only issues is that the position of the graphs is not working. Any ideas? Thanks again! :D

Comment: Can you please give me more details about the position of the graphs?